# Ajax Give Response but not Executing the PHP Service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Am doing Ajax request to a file which sends a mail. It give me the correct response which is "Message Sent" but the mail not sent. When I try to execute that file from the browser with the same GET Headers , it send the mail.

So what's the problem here ?

The ajax request working well and triggered using (success) keyword in jquery to make sure that it succeed.

Help me !

For ajax side :

```
function SendEmail(To, Subject, Message) 
{
 var URL = 'mail-service.php?to=' + To + '&subject=' + Subject + '&msg=' + Message;

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        alert("Message Sent to : " + To);
    }
});
  }
```

for PHP side :

```
<?php
$url = "http://mydomain.com/mail/mail.php?to=".$_GET['to']."&subject=".$_GET['subject']."&msg=".urlencode($_GET['msg']);

$link = fopen($url,"r");

while($res = fread($link,100))
{
    echo $res;
}

fclose($link);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the function, The `success` function of the AJAX request executes once the **request is successful**, it does not care about what the page requested to *did* or *did not*.

To ensure you receive correct messages, you have to setup your PHP processing file, to return the response.

In your script

```
success: function (res) {
    alert(res); //Display the response text
}
```

And make sure your PHP file, return the response text as output.

```
while($res = fread($link,100))
{
    echo $res; //Make sure this is like "Message sent" or "Message sending failed"
}
```

Comment: @Hatem, I dont understand your question.